# Autofac class with default parameter -> Override att runtime

Tags: autofac

I want to be able to resolve a class with default parameters sent to the constructor but i want to be able to override this when i specify a parameter.

Here is how i register:

```cs
builder.RegisterType<SearchService<WebPage>>().As<ISearchService<WebPage>>().WithParameter(
            new NamedParameter("solrUrl", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UrlWeb"])).SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<SearchService<Document>>().As<ISearchService<Document>>().WithParameter(
            new NamedParameter("Url", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["solrUrlDocs"])).SingleInstance();
```

To resolve i would like to be able to this:

```cs
_containerProvider.RequestLifetime.Resolve<ISearchService<WebPage>();
```

which works excellent but i also want to be able to do this:

```cs
_containerProvider.RequestLifetime.Resolve<ISearchService<WebPage>(new NamedParameter("Url", "some other url"));
```

which does not work .. So my question is if it is possible to register with a default parameter which i want to be able to override at runtime??

Comment: In your registration for `SearchService<WebPage>` the parameter is named `solrUrl`.  I think when you resolve you should use the same name `solrUrl`.  However, you are using "Url" which is the parameter name for the `SearchService<Document>` registration.  Autofac determines the parameter names using reflection, so they must be named as they are in the class constructor http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/ResolveParameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is a complete and simple example showing how to override at runtime, a `NamedParameter` configured at registration time.

*Important:  The parameter name you use for the `NamedParameter` must match the parameter name in the constructor of the class you register and then resolve.  In the example below, the parameter for `Thing`'s constructor is `name`.*

```csh
using System;
using Autofac;

namespace BillAndBenConsole
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<Thing>().WithParameter("name", "bill");
            var container = builder.Build();

            Console.WriteLine(container.Resolve<Thing>().Name);//Writes bill
            Console.WriteLine(container.Resolve<Thing>().Name);//Writes bill
            Console.WriteLine(container.Resolve<Thing>(new NamedParameter("name", "ben")).Name);//Writes ben
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Thing
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Thing(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem was that i used link to resolve NamedParameter but it resolved it as IEnumerable<NamedParameter> and hooked up as object parameter instead of IEnumerable<Parameter> .. I tried cast<Parameter> but i got an exception that specified cast is invalid ...                  (from DictionaryEntry argument in arguments select new NamedParameter(argument.Key.ToString(), argument.Value)).Cast<Parameter>().ToList();